# Obufscation, shrinking using build.gradle in Android

Tags: android

What does it mean in code?

```
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
```

As I read:
minifyEnabled set to true allows code shrinking with R8 to be enabled.
but I don't see useProguard set to true, is it true by default?
Does it work in my case?

```
useProguard = true
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Answer (score 3):

Hi there in the new android version it's not necessary to use "useProguard true" anymore.

when you build your project using Android Gradle plugin 3.4.0 or higher, the plugin no longer uses ProGuard to shrink your code. Instead, the plugin works with the R8 compiler by default to handle the responsibility of Shrinking, obfuscating, and optimizing your app.

However you still need the proguard file to mention your rules.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgpyuuzMlo0

One of the best videos on this topic in my opinion , watch this if you can.